# How to determine if a group exists in the SignalR .net core

Tags: .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am practicing making chat rooms with signalr .net core. I want when the user enters the group name and joins the group, I check if that group exists or not?
If it does not exist, it will notify that user back.

Normally I noticed when I use below JoinRoom function if the group doesn't exist then the system will create a new group for me.

```
public async Task JoinRoom(string roomName, string username) 
        {            
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
            await Clients.Group(roomName).SendAsync(username + " joined.");
        }
```

But I just want system to announce the group does not exist and does not need to create a new group.

Anyone can help me plz ??
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Same as some people store connection Id's you can store groups.

You can create a list of groups that you will add and remove as you want and in that case you can also check if group exists.

You create the group list like:

```cs
IList<string> myGroups = new List<string>();
```

Then you create the groups somewhere where you need and create the room validation method:

```cs
public void CreateRoom(string roomName) 
{            
    this.myGroups.Add(roomName);
}

public void DeleteRoom(string roomName) 
{            
    this.myGroups.Remove(roomName);
} 

public bool CheckIfRoomExists(string roomName)
{
    return this.myGroups.Contains(roomName);
}
```

Finally you can check if room exists when joining the room:

```cs
public async Task JoinRoom(string roomName, string username) 
{           
    if (CheckIfRoomExists(roomName));
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
        await Clients.Group(roomName).SendAsync(username + " joined.");
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("The room does not exists!");
    }
}
```

You now adapt this code as you need. For example if the group does not exists, you notify the user that it does not exist and do not throw the exception or maybe you call the create group method, etc...

Comment: Thanks for answering me. I will try it.

Comment: Have you tested this? I don't think the hub is a singleton to do this. But there is a `Context.Features` property you can use to presist

Comment: The hub is always transient. Maybe the best option is to store the group somewhere outside the hub in another service and resolve the service here in the hub @NevilleNazerane